# How to get OS Build number in Windows 10 1809 ISO using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iso, windows-update

We will get the OS Build number every time we build an OS. However I cant find where is the OS Build number inside the windows ISO file. I tried to search from the install.wim but cannot find it. I might miss something. Please let me know where can i get that number.

Example of OS Build number : 18362.239

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So what you have there is `[OS build number].[Updated Build Revision (UBR) number]`. You can get UBR by querying registry. That is the only way i know of.

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name UBR).UBR
```

To get the OS build, you can use the WMI class or registry method.

```
(get-wmiobject -Class win32_OperatingSystem).BuildNumber
```

or

```
(Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name CurrentBuild).CurrentBuild
```

or

```
[system.environment]::osversion.version.build
```

Or from the sysinfo which would be messy.

Now its just a matter of marrying the 2.

Comment: These are for getting the OS build number that currently installed in my pc. What I want is to get the OS build number of Windows Installation ISO (.iso) that I downloaded from Windows webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DISM?

dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:X:\sources\install.wim

Then if you look at the created date  (e.g. If the created date is: 3/19/2017 then the build number is the "1703" = Year & Month of Windows 10 release)  or look at the build number

Answer (score 0):

An ISO file typically comes with several Windows images.

To get the build of, say, the first image of an ISO mounted on `D:` (images list is 1-indexed):

```bsh
(get-windowsimage -imagepath "D:\sources\install.wim" -index 1).build
```